# sample code or projects using simple reference counter in C

Tags: c, garbage-collection, reference-counting

I am wondering how difficult it would be to integrate a reference counting (or other managed memory) regime for managing some of my struct libraries in C.  What sample code would you recommend I look at?

Answer (score 2):

This [garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) is widely used for C (even in gcc)

Answer (score 2):

[Python uses garbage collection](http://docs.python.org/c-api/refcounting.html) based on RC and it also [solves the circular reference problem](http://docs.python.org/c-api/gcsupport.html) (i.e. when you have two or more objects that reference each other but no one else references them; in this case, the ref count will be > 0 but the whole cycle could be collected).

Answer (score 2):

[XMLRPC-c](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) and [json-c](http://oss.metaparadigm.com/json-c/) are examples of C libraries that use reference counting (and have slightly different approaches as to when to increment them behind the scenes) . If you are in a multi-threaded environment, you might also be interested in the [kref](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/Documentation/kref.txt) usage in the Linux kernel.